# How do I update consecutive rows in a mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of values I am trying to enter into a mysql database with a dynamic number of rows.  The variables are stored in $box1, $box2, and so on.  I am trying to use UPDATE to put in the right value ($box1 in the first row selected, $box2 in the second row selected, and so on) in each consecutive row of the table.  I’m not sure what code I have to type in the “while” loop to make this happen.

```
    <?php


        // Retrieve data from Query String
    $box1 = $_GET['box1'];
    $box2 = $_GET['box2'];
    $box3 = $_GET['box3'];
    $box4 = $_GET['box4'];
    $box5 = $_GET['box5'];
    $session = session_id();


        //build query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM sessionid WHERE sessionid='$session' ";

        //Execute query
    $qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        // Insert the right quantity in each row for each consecutive box 
        $i=1;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
            mysql_query("UPDATE `sessionid` SET `qt`='$box' .$i . '' WHERE `sessionid`='$session' ");
            $i++;
            }


    ?>
```

I am now inputting the data from the url on the previous page into an array $box[1].  I keep getting an error saying: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/content/c/a/s/cashme/html/buylooper/change-qt.php on line 13.  Line 13 refers to the line that UPDATE query.  Any tips?

```
//Retrieve data from Query String, input into array, and update table
        $count = $_SESSION['id'];
        for ($i=1; $i<$count; $i++){
                $box[$i] = $_GET['box'. $i .''];
            mysql_query("UPDATE `sessionid` SET `qt`='$box["'. $i .'"]' WHERE `sessionid`='$session' AND `id`='$i' ");
            echo $box[$i];
        }
```

Comment: Coul you please provide us your table schema, and give us more information about *consecutive rows*. Do you mean *consecutive id*? What if there are *blanks* in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A most basic thing you have to learn by heart:

### There are no consecutive rows in the database.

All the rows are completely random.
And you cannot rely on their natural order by any means.

To update a certain row you have to identify it with some unique field. Mysql's standard auto incremented id is the best choice.

Always store the row's id in the form, to be able to know which row current value belongs to.
Make your form like this

```
<input type="text" name"box[1]" value="20">
```

where `1` is an actual row's id

Also note that all data manipulations have to be performed using POST method, not GET.

So, in the `$_POST['box']` you will have an array of pairs `id => value` and can easily construct the update query out of them.

Comment: storing the editing row id in the HTML form is a good idea. and +1 for the most basic thing to learn about databases

Comment: given that I make the changes in the name of the textbox, how do I implement the auto increment id and $_POST?

Comment: as for the  auto increment it is already implemented in your table, I believe. if not - please post the table structure in your question.

Comment: I tried using your approach to use an array but I get a syntax error when I try to do so. I made an edit to the orignal post that shows what I have and the error I get. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you store your variables `$box1` to $box5` in an array instead of 5 variables?

Then you can use `$boxes[$i]` to call the related values.

Answer (score 0):

U need

```
"UPDATE `sessionid` SET `qt`="'.$box.$i . '" WHERE `sessionid`="'.$session.'"
```

Also You should Store the values in Array rather than separate `$box` variables

u shld use

```
$box[]
```

not

```
$box1,$box2, etc...
```

Comment: You're right. I tried using your approach to use an array but I get a syntax error when I try to do so. I made an edit to the orignal post that shows what I have and the error I get.  Any tips?